# Keeping Structs/Constants in separate header

Tags: c++

I have a VECTOR struct that holds 3 integers, i, j, and k. I need to utilize this struct in more than one header file. Is it considered bad practice to move all #defines, and structs, all constants to a separate header file labeled, "Constants.h", or should I define the same struct in each header file where I currently use it?

Comment: This is what a header file for. Declare the struct within a header file and include this header in other files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very **good practice** to move *definitions into header-files*, so that they can be used in different compilation-units. This ensures that all your compilation-units always use the same definitions of your classes and constants (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/333964/160206) for a more elaborate explanation with examples).

It is, however, **bad practice** to *put them all in one header-file*. This makes all compilation-units that use this header-file recompile, even on completely unrelated changes. You should group things together that belong together in some sense - unrelated things should be in different headers. It is sometimes useful to provide one header that includes all, for convenience, but such a feature should only be used for quick prototyping or after careful consideration of the implications - compilation-times can quickly become very long. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/346098/160206) lists some ideas on how to organize your headers.

Note that you should try to avoid macros for constants in C++ - prefer `static const T`, e.g.:

```
static const int foo = 42;
```

Macros are not typesafe and can introduce subtle bugs due to the way are expanded. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96196/when-are-c-macros-beneficial) lists some cases when macros are actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad practice at all. It's generally a good practice to re-use code.